# storing netflow v9 in a time series data base

Tags: netflow

I am looking for a recommendation about a free linux tool that can collect netflow v9 traffic and store the parsed data in a time series data base for further analysis. I don't need analysis capabilities just good reliable collection and storage performance

Comment: Be more specific in your requirements: which timeseries DB for storage, expected flow data scale, how close to realtime you want data to be stored in DB, etc. `pmacct` is a proven collector. Can store data in mysql/postgres, send data to kafka or produce csv files, which you can load to tsdb of your choice, Also have a look at Ntopng, FastNetMon.  Clickhouse DB is good for large scale storage, VictoriaMetrics or InfluxDB are alternatives. There are many other options for collectors and DBs.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm interested in collecting around 100K flows per sec (big commercial routers). I don't have to store the data for long, something like 10m before flushing. I thought about using influxdb

Comment: Keep in mind, that InfluxDB doesn't like high cardinality series. Detailed flow aggregation scheme with keys like source_ip+destination_ip can easily cause troubles.

Comment: If you don't need analytics at all you can just use kafka as a reliable short-term storage.

Comment: A bit late, but maybe check out https://github.com/paihu/netflow_exporter, a NetFlow collector and Prometheus exporter.